# Traversals as multilenses: What would be an example?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm currently working on understanding the `lens` library in detail by following the explanation in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lenses_and_functional_references#The_scenic_route_to_lenses, which starts with a `Traversal` and then introduces the `Lens`. The wiki makes the distinction that a `Traversal` can have multiple targets, while a `Lens` has a single target.

This arguments is also made [in the documentation for `Traversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html), "[Traversals] have also been known as multilenses".

What would be example code to illustrate this distinction? E.g. how can I use a `Traversal` to get or set multiple values in a way I cannot do with a `Lens`?

Comment: Is the example on the wikibooks page (`pointCoordinates` is a `Traversal` and not a `Lens`) inadequate? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for the note! I didn't even make this connection and will look at the `pointCoordinates` example more closely, I think a big part of that will be practically using this Traversal to get and set values.

Comment: @ErikKaplun I see you've put a bounty on this 4-year-old question, but since you haven't made a comment, it's not clear what you're looking for in an answer that you would want to reward. There are plenty of examples of using both Traversals and Lenses around the web, including - as previous comments have pointed out - in the linked wikibook article. If you want to encourage others to give a good answer you should explain more clearly what it is you're looking for that you haven't found elsewhere.

Comment: any answers are welcome. there were zero previously. I’m just curious, not looking for anything specific. so anything you might want to add is appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Not sure if I have anything good to add here (I'm fascinated by Lenses but don't have a huge amount of experience with them or much understanding beyond the basics) but I might have a think!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a type

```hs
data Pair a = Pair a a
```

This offers two natural lenses and two additional natural traversals.

```hs
-- Work with the first or second component
_1, _2 :: Lens' (Pair a) a

-- Work with both components, either left to
-- right or right to left
forwards, backwards :: Traversal' (Pair a) a
```

There are fewer things you can *do* with a traversal than a lens, but you (often) get more traversals than lenses.